# How to switch between multiple tabs(more than 2) open in same window using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am learning Selenium-Webdriver and so for practice working on one scenario, but I'm stuck in step#3. Scenario is as follows:

1. Open google homepage and perform some search, say for the word "WebDriver".
2. Open the first two links in new tabs of the same window.
3. Navigate to the second and third tab and get their titles
4. Close the tabs and switch back to the google result tab.

So far, I'm able to open google home page, perform a search on the word "WebDriver" and open the first two links, but now I'm unable to switch to the second and third tab and close them. My code so far is:

```
    String originalHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
    System.out.println("Before switching title is:" +driver.getTitle());
    String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND,Keys.ENTER);
    WebElement link1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='rso']/div[2]/div[1]/div/h3/a"));
    link1.sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
    WebElement link2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='rso']/div[2]/div[2]/div/h3/a"));
    link2.sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);

    Set<String> s1 = driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> i1 = s1.iterator();
    int i = 0;
    while(i1.hasNext())
    {
        i++;
    String childwindow = i1.next();

    if(!originalHandle.equalsIgnoreCase(childwindow))
    {
    driver.switchTo().window(childwindow);
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    System.out.println("After switching title of new Tab "+i+ " title is " +driver.getTitle());
    driver.close();
    }
}

driver.switchTo().window(originalHandle);
System.out.println("Original window tab title is" +driver.getTitle() );
```

I'm not sure where it's going wrong and how to fix it. :(

Comment: Can you provide the links of the website?

Comment: @saifur 
First Link is google search: https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=EtazVZ2aJKvv8wfrs5yQCA&gws_rd=ssl#q=WebDriver

From that link, I'm trying to open first two results links (which are present on the page) as follows:
1. www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/    

2.http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Answer (score 1):

I searched for such functionality as tab switching but found nothing.
Closest to this is switch of windows. (there are lot of comments that WindowHandles can be used for tab switching, but this is not true  -- I had tried a lot. Its can be used only for windows switch, but not tabs switch)

if you need to open in new window -- you need to click on link with pressed shift btn

code is something like

```
Actions.KeyDown(Keys.Shift).Click(ElementToClick).KeyUp(Keys.Shift).Build().Perform();
```

and if you need to switch the window

```
var _windowsList = new List<String>(Instance.WindowHandles);
Instance.SwitchTo().Window(_windowsList[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be too late, but hope this helps :

```
for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) { //Gets the new window handle
        System.out.println(winHandle);
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);        // switch focus of WebDriver to the next found window handle (that's your newly opened window)              
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code:

```
Set<String> s1 = driver.getWindowHandles();
for(String childwindow : s1) {
   if(!originalHandle.equals(childwindow)) {
       driver.switchTo().window(childwindow);
       System.out.println("Tab title is " + driver.getTitle();
   }
   driver.close();
}
driver.switchTo().window(originalHandle);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get all window handler by below code.
   Set windowHandleSet = driver.getWindowHandles();
2. Loop in the window handler set, switchTo each of them.
   driver.switchTo().window(windowHandleStr);
3. Run command Ctrl+number to switch between different tab in same Firefox window.
   WebElement bodyEle = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
   bodyEle.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "1");

http://www.dev2qa.com/open-multiple-windows-tabs-in-selenium-webdriver/